# How to select a single field for all documents that is non empty in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I was checking if we could display the entire document of a field, only if it is has non empty documents.

See the below data:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "john", "age" : 12 }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Neena", "age" : 23 }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "tony", "age" : 33 }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "rimy", "age" : 55, "adress" : "Vattakuxhi house" }
{ "_id" : 6, "name" : "tony", "age" : 33, "adress" : { "apartment" : 23, "street" : "hormisnager" } }
```

When I use below code:

```
db.student.find({},{_id:0,adress:{apartment:1}})
```

Results:

```
{  }
{  }
{  }
{  }
{ "adress" : { "apartment" : 23 } }
```

But I don't want the empty spaces, what should I do? I googled and tried many ways including different ways of below 2 codes, but did not yield any result.

```
db.student.find({},{_id:0,adress:{apartment:{$exists:true}}})
db.student.find({},{_id:0,adress:{$exists:true}})
```

Thank you in advance.
Happy Coding :)

Comment: like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/30EwgUhZyh9)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

You're on the right track with `$exists`. The first parameter of `db.student.find` is the [query](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/), which specifies *which* documents to select. Your query is `{}`, which means "give me all of the documents in this collection." This includes all of the documents that don't have the apartment field, which is why there are a lot of empty objects after the projection.

### The fix

Instead of using [`$exists`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#-exists) in the projection, use it in the query as follows:

```
db.student.find({"adress.apartment": {$exists: true}}, {_id:0,adress:{apartment:1}})
```

This way, only the documents with the `apartment` field defined will be selected.
Hope this helps!